# Bulk inserting to MongoDB on Replicaset

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, bulkinsert, mongodb-.net-driver

I am working on importing data form SQL to MongoDB

I have a table in SQL with 3081583 records, I started inserting those to MongoDB in a `foreach` loop

It started inserting at 05-06-2014 07:42:27 3081583 records and is still running.

My connection to MongoDB using C# Driver

```
private static MongoDatabase ConnectionOne(string dbName = "test")
{
    var connectionString = "mongodb://username$passwordx.x.x.x:27018"
        + "/admin?slaveOk=true";

    var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);

    var server = client.GetServer();

    var database = server.GetDatabase(dbName);

    return database;
}
```

Is there some thing I can do to improve the insert performance? Is this right way to do the bulk insert of 3081583 records or more?

I am concerned about the performance, as this is a weekly process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can insert in bulk: [Bulk Inserts in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/)

```
IEnumerable<WriteConcernResult> results = collection.InsertBatch(records)
```

That will cut on most of the round trips to the DB which should speed things up.

Comment: Is my connectionstrig good. do I have to specify any write conserns to speed up the process?

Comment: @HaBo well you could turn off journaling and indexes but that has it's own problems. I wouldn't do that on a regular basis.

Comment: @I3arnon It depends on data nature. If it is like logs, it may be appropriate to have probability to silently lose some data for sake of performance gain. Some mixed strategy also could be appropriate, for example, to have every 100th insert acknowledged. It helps to detect errors if something really bad happens.

Comment: Excellent, insert completed very fast with insertBatch

Answer (score 2):

1. You could use bulk insert by passing array of objects to insert command. You need configure ContinueOnError and define error handling strategy. But you should split whole set on chunks so that individual chuck doesn't exceed 16Mb.
2. Generally to improve insert performance you could try to limit amount of indexes on collection, use unacknowledged write concern {w:0, j:0} - ( you would have no confirmation about insert success in this case).

Comment: How to define {w:0, j:0}  in my connection string?

Comment: mongodb://username$passwordx.x.x.x:27018/admin?slaveOk=true&w=0&journal=false

Comment: There are conflicting values in WriteConcern(journal=False,w=0).  When W=0, no other values may be set.

Comment: Finally, mongodb://username$passwordx.x.x.x:27018/admin?slaveOk=true&w=0